# How is my interpretation of matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Before I start, please excuse my jargon and any preconceived notions. I am trying to fix how I think about this. It feels as if I am missing something.

So I understand that matrix multiplication linearly maps a vector or matrix to that basis. It describes a linear transformation, as if the coordinate plane scaled and changed direction.

Let's imagine we have basis vectors and some additional vector.

$$
\hat{i} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\hat{j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix},
V = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The following is the corresponding matrix of those basis vectors. This defines our vector space.

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If we want to linearly map V to the vector space described by A, we multiply. This convention will scale $\hat{i}$'s magnitude by V's x component, and $\hat{j}$'s magnitude by V's y component. Then, these products will be added, creating linearly mapped vector V.

$$
1. \space AV =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
2. \space AV =
3
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+2
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
3. \space AV =
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 \\
 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
4. \space AV =
\begin{bmatrix}
8 \\
8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The scaling part in step #2 I do not get. Why is the x component of $\hat{j}$ relevant to the scaling of V's y component? Maybe I'm starting to understand as I'm writing... A linear mapping is almost like a new coordinate plane. Maybe we can consider $\hat{j}$, "new y plane". If I tried to plot a point on the $\hat{j}$ axis, its new point is a linear mapping that would be described in our terms (Euclidean space): (2, 8) as it was found in step three. This seems correct.

So is this simply a convention to transform linear spaces or just vectors, such that, it can be expressed in Euclidean space terms?

But there is also the addition, step #3 that I am confused about. So I mapped V to both Vectors. OH but I guess the vectors are written in Euclidean space, but represent an x axis and y axis inside the linear mapping. So I can just add the x and y components to get the transformed coordinates. This is because we have the points on a seemingly different 'plane'. I've been stuck on this for days I suppose the Feynman technique really does work (assuming I'm right o_o).

Visual Aide

[Graph representing my math above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSjo7.png)

Please, if you can answer my questions or guide me in a way to break my preconceived notions, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you try to say more specifically what you're confused about?

Comment: What do you mean by „matrix multiplication linearly maps a vector or matrix to that basis“ and „ If we want to linearly map V to the vector space described by A, we multiply“. I think you‘re maybe trying to think of A as a change of basis matrix? But to transform into the $\hat{i}, \hat{j}$ basis you’d actually need the inverse of $A$.

Comment: I suppose I just want guidance on how I think about it, and my use of terminology. I think Henry might have pointed out how my terminology may be wrong. I suppose I meant to say, "Matrix multiplication is a convention to map a vector or many vectors (matrix) to a vector space. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental property of vector spaces is that we can add vectors and we can scale vectors.

$i, j$ represent a basis $B$

In the standard basis, $i = (2,0)$ and $j = (1,4)$

The vector $V = (2,3)$ as represented in the basis $B$

That is $V = 2i + 3j$

But what is $V$ in the standard basis?

$V = 2(2,0) + 3(1,4)$
And we can scalar multiply
$V = (4,0) + (3,12)$
And add vectors
$V = (4+3, 0+12) = (7,12)$ in the standard basis.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s consider an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$. By choosing a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ every vector in $V$ can be described (in a unique way) as a linear combination of elements in that basis, so: $v \in V \Rightarrow v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i$, (the $\alpha_i$ are scalars from the field over which $V$ is defined). With respect to that basis we usually write:

$$
v=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \end{pmatrix}$$

Now we can consider linear transformations of $V$, those are just functions $f$ that map vector to vectors s.t. for all $v,w \in V: f(v+w)=f(v)+f(w)$ and for scalars $\alpha: f(\alpha v)=\alpha f(v)$. Notice that these functions don‘t need a basis, we can however, describe them nicely as a matrix if we choose a basis:

$$
f(v)=f(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f(e_i)
$$

So $f(v)$ is determined only by the different $f(e_i)$. Since $f(e_i) \in V$ we can again write it as a linear combination: $f(e_i)= \sum\limits_{j=1}^n A_{j,i} e_j $, where each $A_{j,i}$ is just a scalar so:

$$
f(v)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^n A_{j,i} e_j= \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n A_{j,i} \alpha_i e_j = \\
\begin{pmatrix}A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} & \dots \\ A_{2,1} & \ddots & \\
\vdots \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \end{pmatrix}
$$

I will call this 2d-Array of numbers associated to $f$ the Matrix $A$. This is the full explaination why matrix multiplication works how it does. There are now many ways how to think about all of this. (I highly suggest 3Blue1Brown‘s video series on Linear Algebra for some nice visualisation, if you haven’t seen it yet).

In your question you talk about how $A$ maps vectors to a different basis. This is also a way of thinking about all of this. Let’s consider a 2 dimensional vector space and a basis $\{\hat{x}, \hat{y}\}$ and a different basis $\{\hat{i}, \hat{j}\}$, if I am given the scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ to describe a given $v$ in terms of the $\{\hat{i}, \hat{j}\}$ basis, i.e. $v=\alpha_1 \hat{i}+ \alpha_2 \hat{j} $, how do I get the scalars to describe it in the $\{\hat{x}, \hat{y}\}$ basis, i.e. $v=\beta_1 \hat{x}+ \beta_2 \hat{y}$. Let’s say I know $\hat{i}= A_{1,1} \hat{x}+ A_{2,1} \hat{y} $ and $\hat{j}= A_{1,2} \hat{x}+ A_{2,2} \hat{y} $. Now

$$
v= \alpha_1 \hat{i}+ \alpha_2 \hat{j}= \alpha_1 (A_{1,1} \hat{x}+ A_{2,1} \hat{y})+ \alpha_2 (A_{1,2} \hat{x}+ A_{2,2} \hat{y})= \\ \begin{pmatrix}A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \\ A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

So $v$ gets sent to $\alpha_1$ times „the first column of $A$“ and „$\alpha_2$ times the second column“.

In your example $v= \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{5}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{5}{4} \hat{i}+ \frac{1}{2} \hat{j}$. So we would actually write:

$$
v= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{4} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}_{\hat{i},\hat{j}}
$$

Now using our change of basis matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{4} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

So the matrix above gives us $v$‘s representation in the $\hat{x}, \hat{y}$ coordinates back!